# How to get mountpoint information from super_block structure

Tags: android, linux-kernel, filesystems, linux-device-driver, ext4

I want to know on which mount point did my device is mounted from super_block structure.

In this function I have super_block structure address with me. Is there anyway to know mount point on which this device is mounted.
https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/tegra/+/android-tegra-moto-2.6.39/fs/ext4/super.c#407

```
Struct super_block 
{ ....
  char *s_id;

}
```

s_id gives the name of mount path.

For example

```
        MOUNT           SUPERBLK     TYPE   DEVNAME             DIRNAME
   ffffffc0b6da0c00 ffffffc0336ec000 ext4   /dev/block/system   /system
```

s_id will give me the name system.

I want to know on which mount point did my device is mounted from super_block structure.

Is there any way to get it.

Thanks in advance for your answers.